# Different dataframe paramenters and results, in just one code

Tags: python

```
    A           B    C
0   Red  2002-01-13  3.9
1   Red  2002-01-14 -4.1
2   Red  2002-01-15  2.3
3  Blue  2006-07-01  4.2
4  Blue  2006-07-02  7.2
5  Blue  2006-07-03  6.1

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print ("a?")
a = float(input())
print ('b?')
b = float(input())
print ("Positive")
c = float(input())
print ("Negative")
d = float(input())

df['X'] = a*df['C']
df['Y'] = b*df['C']

df['Total'] = df['X']+df['Y']

def stop(g):
    cond = g.Total.ge(c) | g.Total.le(d)
    if cond.any():
        return g[cond].iloc[0]
    else:
        return g.iloc[-1]

result = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(stop)
```

If I enter these parameters:

a=6; b=-4; c=10; d=-5

I get next `result`:

```
      A           B    C     X     Y  Total
0    Red  2002-01-14 -4.1 -24.6  16.4   -8.2
1   Blue  2006-07-02  7.2  43.2 -28.8   14.4
```

If I run the code again, but now I enter these other parameters:

a=8; b=-4; c= 40; d=-10

I get next `result`:

```
      A           B    C     X     Y  Total
0   Red  2002-01-14 -4.1 -32.8  16.4  -16.4
1  Blue  2006-07-03  6.1  48.8 -24.4   24.4
```

I must run the code twice to get different `result`.

Is it possible to enter different parameters combinations and run the code just once, getting so many results as parameters combination I´ve entered?

I mean, is it possible to enter Combination_1 and Combination_2 at the beginning of the code:

Combination_1: a=6; b=-4; c=10; d=-5

Combination_2: a=8; b=-4; c= 40; d=-10

Run the code just once, and get `Result_1` and `Result_2`:

`Result_1` (it would correspond to Combination_1):

```
      A           B    C     X     Y  Total
0    Red  2002-01-14 -4.1 -24.6  16.4   -8.2
1   Blue  2006-07-02  7.2  43.2 -28.8   14.4
```

`Result_2` (it would correspond to Combination_2):

```
      A           B    C     X     Y  Total
0   Red  2002-01-14 -4.1 -32.8  16.4  -16.4
1  Blue  2006-07-03  6.1  48.8 -24.4   24.4
```

Note: to simplify the question, I´ve only enter two combinations (Combination_1 and Combination_2). I would like to test nine or ten combinations.

Comment: Do you want the user to enter multiple sets of parameters?

Comment: Yes, I want it..

Comment: Is it possible to store each result to its correspondent set of parameters? I mean, to get an individually Result_1 as result of set parameter_1; an individually Result_2 as result of set parameter_2, etc.... Thank you in advance T. Ray

Comment: I don't quite follow. Are you saying you want to store the parameters along with the results? Can you provide an example of what you want that to look like?

Comment: I want code ask me: set parameters_1 (I´d enter a=6; b=-4; c=10; d=-5); set parameters_2 (I´d enter a=8; b=-4; c= 40; d=-10), etc.... When I´d run the code, program should give me a series of results: Result_1, Result_2, etc.... such I´ve written in my question above

Comment: Ok. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177507/discussion-between-tie-24-and-t-ray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just put the user input in a loop. Collect each parameter set in a list, then iterate over and run each parameter set. Optionally, store the results in another list.

```
def stop(g):
    cond = g.Total.ge(c) | g.Total.le(d)
    if cond.any():
        return g[cond].iloc[0]
    else:
        return g.iloc[-1]

done = False
tests = []
counter = 1

# Take multiple inputs from user
# User enters 4 values separated by space, or 'q' to quit
while not done:
    msg = "Parameters_{}: a, b, c, d (or 'q' to quit): "
    inputs = input(msg.format(counter))
    if not inputs == 'q':
        tests.append([float(x) for x in inputs.split(' ')])
        counter += 1
    else:
        done = True

# To store results
results = {}

# Run test params, print the results
for i, test in enumerate(tests, start=1):

    a, b, c, d = test

    df['X'] = a*df['C']
    df['Y'] = b*df['C']

    df['Total'] = df['X']+df['Y']

    result = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(stop)

    result_name = 'Results_{}'.format(i)

    # In case you want to store the results
    results[result_name] = {'params': test, 'results': result}

print(results['Results_1'])

# Example inputs:
# 6 4 10 -5
# 8 4 40 -10
# q
```

Which give the output:

```
{'params': [6.0, 4.0, 10.0, -5.0],
 'results':
A           B    C     X     Y  Total
0  Blue  2006-07-01  4.2  25.2  16.8   42.0
1   Red  2002-01-13  3.9  23.4  15.6   39.0}
```

**EDIT:** Added example user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
master = []
child = []

n = int(input('Enter the number of combinations you want to enter: '))
for i in range(n):
    child = list(map(float, input().split(' ')))
    master.append(child)

for i in range(len(master)):
    a = master[i][0]
    b = master[i][1]
    c = master[i][2]
    d = master[i][3]

    df['X'] = a*df['C']
    df['Y'] = b*df['C']

    df['Total'] = df['X']+df['Y']

    def stop(g):
        cond = g.Total.ge(c) | g.Total.le(d)
        if cond.any():
            return g[cond].iloc[0]
        else:
            return g.iloc[-1]

    result = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(stop)

    print(result)
```